# Copy installed whmcs from local host to remote host

Tags: copy, localhost, remote-server, whmcs

Is there any solution to copy installed WHMCS on the local host to a remote host (server) without any problem?

Answer (score 1):

When you copy WHMCS from your local server to your remote server ensure you update the configuration.php file with your new database settings. Also go to the database you have copied to the remote host and change any instances of your local server's address (e.g "`http://localhost/...."`) to your remote server's address in the settings database table.

Remember to re-issue your WHMCS license

Answer (score 0):

WHMCS is a predominantly encrypted product, and requires the ionCube loader to be present

Download here http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php